# Should it be Miles of Roads or Miles of Road

Tags: grammatical-number

In the context of:

The town has twenty "miles of roads" to maintain.

[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/road) says it is both *count*, and *non-count*.

Comment: For me,it's of road.

Comment: @Cascabel 'Take me home, country roads' - there's your count version.

Comment: @marcellothearcane "She had a face like 50 miles of [_bad road_."](https://www.phrases.org.uk/bulletin_board/27/messages/254.html). There's your non-count version.

Comment: Either is valid.  In the above example it's a matter of personal choice.  In other cases it would depend on context.

Comment: I agree with @HotLicks.  You can say it either way in that context.  I myself might be inclined to say "roads" if there is a plurality of roads to maintain just so no one wrongly infers that the town only has one road to maintain.  But that's my personal choice. It doesn't have to be yours.

Comment: It could be either. Are emphasizing that there are multiple roads (count noun) or that there is lots of road material (mass noun)?

Comment: @JasonBassford or maybe both, that there are lots of road material spread across lots of different roads...

Comment: If you want to be clear, use *lane miles* or *center-line miles*. [Today, the Virginia Department of Transportation (VDOT) maintains 57,867 center-line miles (over 125,000 lane miles) network and it is divided into these categories ...](https://www.vaasphalt.org/asphalt-facts/facts-about-virginias-asphalt/)

Answer (score 2):

For words that are both countable and non-countable, I would use the plural for unitless numbers expressing multitude, and the singular for physical quantities with a unit.

- There are *dozens of roads* leading to Rome.
- The town has *twenty miles of road* to maintain.
- The barrel contains *tens of thousands of grains*. (I meant *grain* as a seed, not as a unit, but the sentence is correct for both interpretations.)
- It takes *several pounds of grain* to produce one pound of meat.

Comment: You remind me of the common idiom: *"All roads lead to Rome."*